# Finding a confidence interval for an unknown distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Problem:

A manufactures of times wants to advertise a mileage interval that excludes
no more than $10\%$ of the milage on tired he sells. All he knows is that for
a large number of tires tested, the  mean milage with $25,000$ miles, with  a
standard deviation of $4,000$. What interval would you suggest?

Answer:

In this case, I am going to apply Tchebysheff's Theorem.
\begin{align*}
u &= 25000 \\
\sigma &= 4000 \\
P(|Y - u | \leq k\sigma ) &\geq 1 - \dfrac{1}{k^2} = 0.1 \\
1 - \dfrac{1}{k^2} &= 0.1 \\
-\dfrac{1}{k^2} &= -0.9 \\
\dfrac{1}{k^2} &= \dfrac{3}{10} \\
k^2 &= \dfrac{10}{3} \\
k &= \pm \sqrt{ \dfrac{10}{3} } \\
k \sigma &\doteq 13333.333 \\
\end{align*}
The lower bound of the answer is:
$$25000 - 4000\left( \sqrt{ \dfrac{10}{3}} \right) $$
Hence the answer is:
$$ ( 11666.667, 38333.333 ) $$
Note: The book's answer is:
$$ ( 12,351, 37,649 ) $$
Where did I  go wrong?

Here is an updated solution which I believe is correct:

Answer:
\newline
In this case, I am going to apply Tchebysheff's Theorem.
\begin{align*}
u &= 25000 \\
\sigma &= 4000 \\
P(|Y - u | \leq k\sigma ) &\geq 1 - \dfrac{1}{k^2} = 0.9 \\
1 - \dfrac{1}{k^2} &= 0.9 \\
-\dfrac{1}{k^2} &= -0.1 \\
\dfrac{1}{k^2} &= \dfrac{1}{10} \\
k^2 &= 10 \\
k &= \pm \sqrt{ 10 } \\
k \sigma &\doteq 12649.111 \\
\end{align*}
The lower bound of the answer is:
$$25000 - 4000\left( \sqrt{ \dfrac{10}{3}} \right) $$
Hence the answer is:
$$ ( 12350.9,  37649.1 ) $$
Note: The book's answer is:
$$ ( 12,351, 37,649 ) $$
Hence they match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $P(|Y-u|\leq k\sigma) \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2} = 0.9$ since you want 90% chance to be inside the interval